# Error UnableToOpenPixelCache in ImageMagick

Tags: python, imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

I am using ImageMagick (PythonMagick).
I want to combine images to an image.

My composite funtion is below

```
def composite_images(sourceImage, destImage, x1, y1):
    op = PythonMagick.CompositeOperator.OverCompositeOp
    type = sourceImage.type
    sourceImage.composite(destImage, x1, y1, op)
    sourceImage.type = type
    return sourceImage
```

I run a loop and it runs well if the count of loop is not large.
However, when I run a loop with a large range (approximate 1900), it causes the error

> RuntimeError: Magick: UnableToOpenPixelCache
>   `Original/images/xxx.png': Too many open files @
>   error/cache.c/OpenPixelCache/3957

Please help me to solve this issue, thank you very much.

Comment: How is the example method being called? From your description, and the error message, it sounds like your not deallocating `sourceImage` & `destImage` correctly. I would speculate that the application design should be altered to allow Python/ImageMagick to free resource back into the system.

Comment: @emcconville It seems to look like this issue: https://github.com/ImageMagick/ImageMagick/issues/202